# use ruby gem capybara webkit to visit web page, get error: Unable to load URL because of error loading (InvalidResponseError)

Tags: ruby, webkit, capybara, capybara-webkit, webautomation

I've developed an automation script by using ruby and capybara webkit to visit a webpage,
But I encountered an error which is "Unable to load URL: https://www.google.com/ because of error loading https://www.google.com/: Unknown error (Capybara::Webkit::InvalidResponseError)"

Here is my code and my ENV is Mac Sierra(10.12.3), capybara (2.12.1)
capybara-webkit (1.12.0), ruby (2.1.3), I've read lots of posts about the same error msg too, but still cant figure out what's happening, Thanks a lot.

```html
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/webkit'

Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.run_server = false
  config.app_host = 'https://www.google.com'
  config.current_driver = :webkit
  config.default_max_wait_time = 30
end

Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
  config.debug = true
  config.allow_unknown_urls
  config.timeout = 30
end

include Capybara::DSL
visit('https://www.google.com')
```

Comment: Your code as posted works fine for me - What version of Qt did you build capybara-webkit with?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole thx to your replay, reinstall ruby, rvm and gems ... etc slove my issue